# could pass environment variables to docker container OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker

I'm able to run docker below docker run command and it is working fine.

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

When I pass environment variables to the docker container then it is failing.

```
docker run -it ubuntu  -e 'ENV_DEPLOY=dev' -e 'CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster' bash
```

The error is

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"-e\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I've tried different variants of the above command but still failing with same error.

```
docker run -it ubuntu  -e ENV_DEPLOY="dev" -e CLUSTER_NAME="MyCluster" bash

docker run -it ubuntu  -e ENV_DEPLOY=dev -e CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster bash

docker run -it ubuntu  -e ENV_DEPLOY='dev' -e CLUSTER_NAME='MyCluster'  bash

docker run -it ubuntu bash  -e ENV_DEPLOY='dev' -e CLUSTER_NAME='MyCluster'
```

The images that I try to run as containers are all in created status when I do `docker ps -a`.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writting it in the incorrect order.

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So you should write:

```
docker run -it -e 'ENV_DEPLOY=dev' -e 'CLUSTER_NAME=MyCluster' ubuntu bash
```